# How to scroll a fixed div inside overflowing parent div

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have been struggling with this for some time now. I need to have a div that should be `position: fixed;` when it's parent is scrolled horizontally, but it should scroll along with the rest of the content when moved vertically. On top of that it needs to look smooth.

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devboell/sczpY/). The problem here is that the fixed div when scrolled upwards does not go out of view when it reaches the parent top border.

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009108/absolutely-positioned-div-inside-scroll-div-moves-jumpily) already, but didn't get useful replies unfortunately. The jsfiddle there reflects better what I am working towards.

I have seen a lot questions that come close to what I am asking for, but these are often solved in a "sticky" way. Many answers deriving from this [article](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/), but I think I am asking for something different.

Please help, I am really stuck :-)

ps: there examples where the fixed div scrolls out of the browser window, but not out of a parent div.

EDIT: I did find solutions for the case where scrollbars are moved individually. However, if you drag diagonally the solutions don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have what you need.  I managed to positioned the green child element (`#container2`) such that it remains fixed when you scroll horizontally, and then retains its horizontal offset when the inner content scrolls vertically.

The **jQuery** is:

```
var $container = $("#container");
var $content1 = $("#content1");
var $content2 = $("#content2");

var content2InitTop = $content2.offset().top;
var content2InitLeft = $content2.offset().left;


$container.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var scrollLeft = $(this).scrollLeft();

    if (scrollLeft == 0 && scrollTop == 0) {
        $content2.removeClass('fixed');
        $content2.offset({
            'top': content2InitTop,
            'left': content2InitLeft
        });
    }

    if (scrollLeft > 0) {
        $content2.addClass('fixed');
        $content2.offset({
            'top': content2InitTop - scrollTop
        });
    } 

    if (scrollTop > 0) {
        $content2.removeClass('fixed');
        $content2.offset({
            'top': content2InitTop - scrollTop,
            'left': content2InitLeft
        });
    } else {
        $content2.offset({
            'left': content2InitLeft
        });
    }
});
```

and the **CSS** is:

```
div, body {
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 0px;
    border : 0px;
}
#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 45px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 5px solid pink;
}
#inner {
    width: 800px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
#content1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}
#content2 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
#content2.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

and the demo fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7Aw6M/

Comment: I need to leave for a while and will check back later and answer questions if needed.

Comment: Brilliant! this definitely solves the question I posed here. I'll try to work it into my existing code now. I may indeed have follow-up questions, but I think I can figure it out. Thanks man, really!!

Comment: You are very welcome, your initial fiddle was a big help, so your persistence paid off.  This was a neat problem to solve!

Comment: well, if you go to the other question I mentioned, there are some easy reputation points up for grabs for you :-) I do apologize for the code there, it a bit messier.

Comment: btw, I could update that code there myself, if you just leave a short answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is only possible with:

```
position:absolute
```

You can not let a parent hide overflow for a fixed element.

http://jsfiddle.net/sczpY/7/

Comment: thanks - I did try that way, but I didn't succeed in having the content divs move smoothly enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/MPsFC/1/

everything works fine. I added some code

```
        var $container = $("#container");
    var $content1 = $("#content1");
    var $content2 = $("#content2");

    var content2InitTop = $content2.offset().top;

    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    $container.on('scroll', function() {
        var scrollTop =  $(this).scrollTop();
        var scrollLeft = 0 - $(this).scrollLeft();           


        if (scrollTop <= lastScrollTop) {

            $content2.addClass('fixed');
            $content2.offset({'top' : content2InitTop - scrollTop});
        }
        else {

            $content2.removeClass('fixed');
        }           

    });
```

Comment: thanks, but I guess I forgot to mention that the div contents can be dragged also. If you drag diagonally, the green div moves horizontally

Comment: In your jsfiddle example the divs are not draggable.. can you post detailed code or update jsfiddle?

Comment: I mean dragging the background of the parent div (the inner div in this case), not the the content divs themselves