# Making header act like google chrome mobile app address bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a header that I have fixed to the top of the window. I have it appear when the user scrolls up and disappear when the user scrolls down. Right now it just uses `.show()` and `.hide()`. I am trying to get it to act like the address bar on the google chrome mobile app i.e. when the user scrolls up the nav bar is stationary until the top of the window reaches the top of the nav div.

If there is anything you do not understand please ask

here is the jquery that I have so far

```
    $(window).scroll(
{
    previousTop: 0
}, 
function () {
var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

if (currentTop < 80) {
    $('#top').css ({position: 'absolute'});
} else {
    $('#top').css ({position: 'fixed'});
    if (currentTop < this.previousTop) {
        $("#top").show();
    } else {
        $("#top").hide();
    }
    this.previousTop = currentTop;
}
});
```

Comment: To the person who down voted this: It helps to add an explanation as to why you voted it down so the OP can fix the problem now and in the future. This looks like a pretty well written question, so I voted it back to 0

Comment: @leigero thank you! do you have any idea how i can go about fixing this or making it happen? the answer to the question that is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Prototype Using jQuery - Version 2

I worked on this problem again and made the action a lot smoother.

The jQuery code looks like:

```
init = {
    previousTop: 0,
    headerHeight: 52
}

$(window).scroll(init,function () {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollMax =  $(document).height() - $(window).outerHeight(true);
    var bodyHeight = $(window).outerHeight(true);
    var scrollType = "";

    if (currentTop < init.previousTop) {
        $(".offset b").text(currentTop);
        $(".offset em").text("Up");
       scrollUp = true;        
    } else {
        $(".offset b").text(currentTop);
        $(".offset em").text("Down");
       scrollUp = false;        
    }

    if (scrollUp == true) {
        $(".header").css({"color": "blue"});
        $(".header").css({"top": currentTop});
    } else {
        $(".header").css({"color": "yellow"});
        if (scrollMax - currentTop < init.headerHeight) {
            $(".header").css({"top": 0});
        }
    }

    /* Optional - to display values of various attributes */    
    $(".previousTop b").text(init.previousTop);
    $(".headerHeight b").text(init.headerHeight);
    $(".bodyHeight b").text(bodyHeight);
    $(".scrollMax b").text(scrollMax);

    init.previousTop = currentTop;
});
```

and the demo fiddle is at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/gmkum/

**How This Works**

There are four key ideas here that make this work.

(1) The code around `currentTop < init.previousTop` is designed to determine if 
you are scrolling up or down.  This is done by comparing the current `.scrollTop`
position from that of the previous scroll event.

(2) If you scroll up, you position the header to the top of the window so it is visible.

(3) When you scroll down, you leave the top offset as is and since the header is 
absolutely positioned, it simply scroll off the top of the screen along with the content.

(4) There is an interesting case near the maximum scroll position.  In case there is not 
enough scroll position left to move the header off the screen, set the top offset to 0 to 
move it out of the way.

Comment: Please remember to up vote this answer and the previous one that I worked on.  This is fairly advanced stuff and it deserves some acknowledgement.  Thanks!

Comment: thank you for the code. There is a couple questions I have. It works but when I scroll up it jerks around is there any way that you can set the position to fixed after it reaches the top of the header, that way it is smoother? Second one is when you scroll down the header stays until you pass its height, is there any way you can have that same effect when scrolling up so its stationary until you pass the height then it becomes fixed? Thank you so much

Comment: The design you are working on can have a lot of variation in behavior.  Could you actually create an image with arrows and labels to explain (ideally) the behavior that you want, and then update your question accordingly.  Otherwise, this is no longer a simple question but more of a design project.  Thanks!